# Strong examples of tech startups going (or staying) with .NET?

Tags: .net

I am looking for specific examples of vibrant, *acquirable* (or acquired) tech concerns, especially startups, that chose to build on the Microsoft stack and either succeeded or appear likely to.

Writely is an obvious example, as is NewsGator, PageFlakes, and StackOverflow itself.

I don't mean this to be a language debate. I hope the question is not too subjective for SO; I and the team I work with have benefited greatly from the solutions to coding quandaries that can be found here, and I expect that the people who could best answer the question frequent this site.

To make the question a little more specific, let's say you are a .NET expert and a member of a startup who is at a turning point. That turning point may or may not involve a shift in platforms. Avoiding subjective arguments, what quantifiable examples - companies or case studies - can you point to in favor of going or staying with .NET? (Extra points for examples in the Valley.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [Microsoft's BizSpark startup directory](http://microsoftstartupzone.com/BizSparkDB/Pages/Company_Directory.aspx).

This shows most of the new startups taking advantage of BizSpark (which will be any that are intelligent, using Microsoft technologies).  Most of these are likely .NET oriented.

Comment: Good suggestion; thanks, and voted up. I would also suggest http://www.asp.net/ajax/showcase/, generally more for a "what can be done" set of examples than "big winners on the MS stack" set of examples.

Comment: I like the answer but keep in mind that startups with over $1mm in annual revenue are no longer BizSpark-eligible, which would weed out some of your examples.

Comment: @tlianza: Although - I'd also say, once you're reaching $1000000 in revenue annually, are you still a startup?

Comment: I'd say so... a barely breakeven company with @10 employees could be well within that range.